# Can i submit a revised version of a retracted paper to another journal

Tags: publications, publishers, errors-erratum, retraction

One of my paper was retracted die to honest error (statistical error). is it possible to submit the revised version of the paper to another journal for consideration of publication. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE, Aliyu Mashud! Please elaborate on your honest statistical error.

Answer (score 1):

Of course! If you couldn't submit the revised paper elsewhere, it would be dead to the world - never to be published - which is not a desirable outcome if your paper contains new results.

Comment: I think it somewhat depends on *why* the paper was retracted.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov the OP said it's an honest error + it's been revised, so I assume the problem's been corrected.